# Cloth is rendering weirdly

Tags: rendering, camera, cloth-simulation

[image]The object with cloth and subsurf modifier is bending very badly in the render.I don't get the same thing in the viewport and in the render.The deformation seems reduced when I apply the the subsurf modifier,but this is not what I want.Where does this problem come from and what should I do to avoid the bad deformation?[image]

Comment: The bad deformation desappears when I recalculate the normals and playing the animation from the beginning of the frame